# Why isn't _MethodInfo interface called IMethodInfo in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methodinfo

I was just reading through the `MethodInfo` type and came across this type and thought it was some sort of unmanaged class of some sort at first. Then saw that it's actually an interface.

Anyone knows why it wasn't named `IMethodInfo`? I thought prefixing interfaces with `I` was standard practice in .NET. Is it because of some naming collision?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because it's a COM visible interface and that's a convention in COM:

```
[ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), TypeLibImportClass(typeof(MethodInfo)), Guid("FFCC1B5D-ECB8-38DD-9B01-3DC8ABC2AA5F"), CLSCompliant(false)]
public interface _MethodInfo
```

Comment: What's a convention in COM? ``IMethodInfo`` would have been a quite by-convention name in COM. Like, e.g., ``ICorRuntimeHost`` from the same .NET CLR.